# How to keep looping till a function returns?

Tags: c++

I am using a C++ graphics library which has functions `void WaitForMouseDown()` and `void WaitForMouseUp()`. The WaitForMouseDown function waits until the mouse button is pressed and then returns.  WaitForMouseUp waits for the button to be released.
There is another function in the library `bool isMouseDown()` which returns `true` if the mouse button is currently down.

Now, I have to start doing something in a loop when the user clicks the first time, and keep looping until user presses the mouse the second time.

I have tried the following approach, but for some reason the program crashes after the second click. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

```
int main(){
   WaitForMouseUp();
   while(!isMouseDown()){
      //do something
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? What message do you get? And are you sure it isn't the `do something` part itself that does the crashing rather than the mouse routines?

Comment: The xcode console and the graphics window both freeze. I dont get any  error message. I guess you are right, if I comment out the `do something`, then it works fine. On the other hand, the `do something` code seems to run fine until user makes the second click.

Comment: Have you tried adding a sleep in the loop? like a sleep(100). Just a suggestion!

Comment: NOTE: this probably isn't relevant but shouldn't it be `int main(){` and not `int main{` ?

Comment: By the way, if your description is accurate (program must wait for mousedown, then do something until a second mousedown), your program code doesn't match: it immediately starts doing something until the first mousedown and then exits.

Comment: If you just have your program run the `do something` code a couple of times without the mouse code, does it work correctly?

Comment: Why not just use `WaitForMouseUp` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `//do something` does not include polling the mouse or acting on windowing system events (i.e. no call to your library), you've got the obvious infinite loop here: `isMouseDown` will always return `true` because the event that would set it to `false` sleeps in your event queue.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand correctly. Isn't `isMouseDown` always `false`, that is why the loop keeps on running. Now, when I make the second click 'isMouseDown' becomes `true` and hence the loop condition `!isMouseDown` becomes `false` and breaks the loop. This works absolutely fine if I comment out `do something`.

Comment: @stressed_geek: Yes, but `isMouseDown` doesn't magically become `true`, but rather gets so when the GUI library processes a mouse event. Which it might do in a parallel thread, but for most frameworks something like a call to `process_pending_events()` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
int main()
{
  WaitForMouseUp();
  bool done = false;
  while(!done) {
  //do something
  done = isMouseDown();
  }
```

Comment: Which is equivalent to `do { // do something } while ( ! isMouseDown() );`